# Inserting rows based upon quanity in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I returning 3-8 rows from a query that I am returning from a table.  I need to turn each of these rows into multiple rows in another table based upon the quantity.

For example:

I have an array which is comprised of a device type, device name, quantity and price.

```
$devices = array
  (
  array("laptop","A-100",5,300),
  array("laptop","B-105",1,450),
  array("printer","CP21",3,125),
  array("monitor","vision21",1,100)
  );
```

What would be the best way to insert this into a separate database table so that it creates multiple records for each device type based upon the quanity?   Example:

```
laptop     A-100      300
laptop     A-100      300
laptop     A-100      300
laptop     A-100      300
laptop     A-100      300
laptop     B-105      450
printer    CP-21      125
printer    CP-21      125
printer    CP-21      125
monitor    vision 21  100
```

I have tried to find anything online which could provide direction on this.  The closest i could find was running foreach loops, but I cant see how I could run a foreach loop and return what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you won't find anything that does this directly. you'd need two loops. one to loop on the main array, then a sub-loop to loop on that "quantity" field, doing an insert however many times necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little messy but should do it

```
$devices = array
      (
      array("laptop","A-100",5,300),
      array("laptop","B-105",1,450),
      array("printer","CP21",3,125),
      array("monitor","vision21",1,100)
      );
    $array = array();
    foreach($devices as $key=>$device){

        for($i=0;$i<$device[2];$i++){
        $array[] = array($device);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep.  It works like a charm.  I spent hours and hours trying to find a solution.  Thank You!!!!!